# Why I can't use wget command in SSH shell?

Tags: ssh, shell, wget, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have the following problem.

I am using my RaspBerry (with RaspBian installed) by **SSH**.

My problem is that I can't use **wget** command because it fails.

For example if I try to execute the following command:

```
sudo wget http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
```

I obtain this error message:

```
--2014-05-29 19:39:11--  http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
Resolving dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address `dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com'
pi@raspberrypi ~/driverWireless $ sudo wget http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
```

The strange thing is that I can ping it:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/driverWireless $ ping dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com
PING dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (192.0.80.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (192.0.80.175): icmp_req=1 ttl=41 time=164 ms
64 bytes from dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (192.0.80.175): icmp_req=2 ttl=41 time=167 ms
```

Why? What can I do to solve this issue?

(on my Ubuntu Linux system I have no problem to perform wget command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your version of wget on the pi. Try forcing IPv4, rather letting it try to use IPv6:

```
sudo wget -4 http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
```

The `-4` will restrict it to IPv4.